# Increase and decrease video speed netstream

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, netstream

I'm developing a player using action script 3. I want to add an option that allow users to increase or decrease the speed of the current video. How can I do that with NetStream?

Comment: You have to use `appendBytes`. Do you know your way around FLV bytes? You change the timestamp before feeding a frame (video Tag) to the decoder. Shorter timesamp == faster playback and vice versa. I have an old demo somewhere on my HDD (will upload later).

Comment: Can you give me an example? thx

Comment: An example how? You have to write the code around the specific codec of the video. If you show me how you extract a video tag I will edit the code to show how to adjust the timestamp bytes. Also read this **[FLV Specs PDF](http://download.macromedia.com/f4v/video_file_format_spec_v10_1.pdf)**. Is your video at least inside a FLV container? Do you know about bytes? If you've never handled bytes in AS3 this might be too much to attempt for a beginner. Note you can speed adjust the picture by timestamps but for sound that needs decoding to PCM format before any effecting then appending...